# New line character within at*smsm2m message string

Tags: telnet, gsm, at-command

I'm trying to send a multiline sms from an application I am creating to my phone via telnet to a GSM modem. I would like the message to be output to my phone as shown below but cannot figure out how to add new lines within the message string so that the message is output to my phone as below. I cannot find much documentation on this either and the few character codes (`\r\n`) I tried either terminated the telnet command were they were displayed in my code or were showing in the SMS received on my phone.

Does anybody know what character code that would give me a new line without terminating the telnet command within the message string?

```
at*smsm2m= “441234567891
Pinging 192.168.0.31 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.0.31: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64<br>
Reply from 192.168.0.31: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64<br>
Reply from 192.168.0.31: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64<br>
Reply from 192.168.0.31: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.31:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
    Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
```

Answer (score 0):

The server side of Telnet is typically just a regular shell so you can do the same things you'd do for embedded newlines as if you were typing at a command line.  Try this:

```
echo -e "this\nhas\nmultiple\nlines" | program
```

(you may need to look up flags for the `echo` command on the server if it's not a GNU machine)